# row radio button - Change the color of the selected row

Tags: lightning-web-components, css

I'm trying to change the background color of the selected row in a table, but having some issues with it.

I'm trying to select the row and catch it with event, and later change the color for the event.target

a little help will be much appreciated.

this is my HTML:

```
   <div class="products-row tableHeader">
      <div class="products-cell" key={col.label} for:each={testColObj} for:item="col">{col.label}</div>
   </div>

  <div class="products-row" key={rowItem.Account.Id} for:each={testObjData} for:item="rowItem" data-id={rowItem.Account.Id}>
    <div class="products-cell">
         <input
             type="radio"
             name="selectedRow"
             value={choseSelected}
             id={rowItem.Account.Id}
             onchange={changeChoose}/>
      </div>
      <div class="products-cell">
       <span>{rowItem.Account.Id}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="products-cell">
       <span>{rowItem.Account.Name}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="products-cell">
       <span>{rowItem.Account.Industry}</span>
      </div>
 </div>
```

And my JS is:

```
 changeChoose(event){
        console.log(event.target.id);    
        this.choseSelected = event.target.id;
        event.target.style.backgroundColor ='blue';

    }
```

On the developer console, when I'm changing the products-row for the specific row in the HTML, it works, but I'm not sure how to apply it in the JS file.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code where we can use `currentTarget` to get the value of clicked div & query the element to set its css properties:

```
changeChoose(event){
   console.log(event.target.id);    
   this.choseSelected = event.target.id;
   this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${event.currentTarget.dataset.id}"]`).style.background = "blue"; 
}
```

There's a nice stack exchange [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086427/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-currenttarget-property-and-target-property) about *currentTarget VS target*.

Although above code will work , I would prefer to use js add method to add(or toggle [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as per your requirement) css classes using below approach :

```
changeChoose(event){
    console.log(event.target.id);    
    this.choseSelected = event.target.id;
    const selectedDiv = this.template.querySelector(`[data-id="${event.currentTarget.dataset.id}"]`);

     if(selectedDiv) {
        selectedDiv.classList.add("background-cls");
     }
}
```

In css file for LWC , add a class as below :

```
.background-cls {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

Also , you would need handling for previously selected divs as per my understanding.